# jQuery Hide / Show not working on iOS

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make hide and show loading bar on my website 
I tested on Android and PC it working well 
but it not working for ios please take a look.

Jquery

```
  echo' <script> ';
    echo' $(document).ready(function(){ ';
    echo'     $("#btn").click(function(){ ';
    echo"        $('#btn').hide(); ";
     echo'    }); ';
     echo'    $("#btn").click(function(){ ';
      echo'       $("#loading").show(); ';
     echo'    }); ';
    echo' });';
    echo'</script>';
```

HTML

```
echo"       <a class='btn btn-success margin btn-block btn-lg' id='btn' href='" . $loginUrl . "'>Click to Play</a>";
echo'           <img style="display:none;" class="img-responsive img center-block" id="loading" src="loading.gif"/> ';
```

Comment: Please edit the question and paste your code.

Comment: @Narayan updated

Answer (score 0):

What if You add timeout to show/hide?

```
  $('#btn').hide(250);
  $("#loading").show(250);
```

Comment: it don't mean it timeout but i just not show and hide in ios devices

Comment: I know, but try adding timeout and check if it helps on iOS

Comment: still the same bro :( 
wait i record video for you